# custom image size into devise + facebook-omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth, mongoid3

I'm using mongoid, rails 3.2.10 and omniauth on devise.. and trying to set up custom image_size of facebook profile image url

```
 config.omniauth :facebook , API_KEYS['facebook']['api_key'], API_KEYS['facebook']['api_secret'], :image_size => {:width => 100, :height => 100}
```

I configured as above..
but result is as below..

```
http://graph.facebook.com/636937446/picture?type=#<OmniAuth::Strategy::Options height=100 width=100>
```

so i checked out the facebook-omniauth Strategy.rb file. please tell what should i do..

```
  def image_url uid, options
    uri_class = options[:secure_image_url] ? URI::HTTPS : URI::HTTP
    url = uri_class.build({:host => 'graph.facebook.com', :path => "/#{uid}/picture"})

    query = if options[:image_size].is_a?(String)
      { :type => options[:image_size] }
    elsif options[:image_size].is_a?(Hash)
      options[:image_size]
    end
    url.query = Rack::Utils.build_query(query) if query

    url.to_s
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same problem. I actually edited my `strategy.rb` file, added my custom function and it worked perfect.

On line 39: change it to `'image' => image_url(uid,options),`

Next edit the image_url method to something like this

```
  def image_url uid, options
    query = if options[:image_size].is_a?(String)
      { :type => options[:image_size] }
    elsif options[:image_size].is_a?(Hash)
      options[:image_size]
    end
    url = build_url("https://graph.facebook.com/","#{uid}/picture",query) if query

    url.to_s
  end
```

Here I call another method called `"build url"`. So just after the image_url method define the `"build url"`

```
  def build_url(domain,path,params)
      return domain + "#{path}?".concat(params.collect { |k,v| "#{k}=#{CGI::escape(v.to_s)}" }.join('&')) if not params.nil?
  end
```

Save the file and thats it!! Hope it works for you!!!

Comment: Oh and dont forget to add `require 'cgi'` as a requirement at the top of the file.